# How I can resolve gradle sync issue on Android Studio 2.0?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc4Mb.png)

I've installed it as it is directed in the pic, but it never seems to be resolved. 
I'd be on cloud nine, if somebody could help me with this.

Comment: Update your extras in SDK manger

Comment: can you show your root gradle screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the correct version that you can add in your build.gradle according to the API needs.

API 22:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

API 23:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

According to your problem in your gradle file you must put below line,

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I'm on cloud nine. FINALLY.

Comment: @Anon glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Click on blue link as and update your sdk...when you will update it, it again gives you error (to update gradle version) so again click on error link then finally Android Studio will work perfectly.